# Can Index Calculus take advantage of small unknown?

Tags: discrete-logarithm, modular-arithmetic

The [Index Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_calculus_algorithm) algorithm solves the [Discrete Logarithm Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm) of finding $x$ with $g^x\bmod p=b$ given $g$, $b$, and prime $p$. Assume $g$ is a generator, so that $x$ is uniquely defined in $[1,p)$.

Can Index Calculus take advantage of $x$ much smaller than $p$?

If so, how low must $x$ be, and what's the saving? Is there a threshold for $x$ such that IC beast GNFS? How low must $x$ be for Baby Step / Giant Step and other algorithms with cost $\mathcal O(\sqrt x)$ modular multiplications to take back the lead?

Comment: No, otherwise DSA couldn't get away with subgroups much smaller than the prime.

Comment: @Samuel Neves: I do not immediately see how we can turn an hypothetical algorithm solving the question's problem into one solving the DLP problem in a DSA/Schnorr group. The difference is that in the present problem $g$ is a generator of the whole group modulo $p$.

Comment: Perhaps [Diffie-Hellman](https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-68339-9_29) with [short exponents](https://www.iacr.org/cryptodb/archive/2004/PKC/3436/3436.pdf) would be a more direct example. The running time of, to my knowledge, all the index calculus variants is not dependent on the exponent or subgroup, only on the prime.